# struggling with Jquery ui accordion plugin

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have built this accordion using the jquery ui accordion plugin, I sort of understand how it works but I am stuggling to find the correct way for the accordion to close on mouse out. I would also like for my own arrow icons to swap for a down arrow when an accordion section  is open. Here is the fiddle:[jquery accordion plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/Z6LWH/)

Any help appreciated even if it sjust pointing in the right direction. The most important thing is to collapse on mouseout

Comment: I understand there us a lot of questions on this but I can't find the answers I am looking for

Comment: On a side note, `id` is designed to be a unique identifier on a DOM element, therefore if you've got a common `id` amongst elements, you're better off using a `class` as the selector. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6LWH/14/)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        event: 'click',
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        icons: {
            "header": "yourIconClassClosed",
            "headerSelected": "yourIconClassOpen"
        }
    }).on('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).accordion( "option", "active", false );
    }).children('li').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $(this).find('h3').trigger('click');
    });
});
```

EDIT: You have to consider my reconstructed HTML:

```
<div id="helpmenu">
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>
        <h3><a href="#">About us</a></h3>
        <div class="accordhidden">
            <ul>
                <li>List item one</li>
                <li>List item two</li>
                <li>List item three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
   <li>
       <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
        <div class="accordhidden">
            <ul>
                <li>List item one</li>
                <li>List item two</li>
                <li>List item three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
        <div class="accordhidden">
            <ul>
                <li>List item one</li>
                <li>List item two</li>
                <li>List item three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
        <div class="accordhidden">
            <ul>
                <li>List item one</li>
                <li>List item two</li>
                <li>List item three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3><a href="#">Section 4</a></h3>
        <div class="accordhidden">
            <ul>
                <li>List item one</li>
                <li>List item two</li>
                <li>List item three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a hover version of this?

Comment: It is hover, isn't it? I just bind accordion to click and then trigger it so you can use both mouseover and click functionality...

Comment: Did you use the same HTML as I? I don't think so because you see that it works in the fiddle ;)

Comment: I did, the site I have entered this into only has jquery 1.4.2 (can't change it) would this make a difference it has UI 1.8.9 too

Comment: Erm well, you set up your fiddle with jQuery 1.7, it seems like the latest UI version for 1.4.4 (on jsfiddle) doesn't even have accordion...

Comment: sorry I have UI 1.8.9 and Jquery 1.4.2

Comment: I just changed it on the fiddle and Its the version that's causing the problem my bad, I will try and get our libraries updated

Answer (score 0):

This may answer part of your question

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6LWH/1/

Comment: thank you Donlad that works but when you mouse out from the sub menu its doesn't, how do I get it to collapse when mouseout from the whole accordion

Comment: Move the About us inside the accordion div. Might be an oversight

Answer (score 0):

Another part to the solution: [set icon classes](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6LWH/7/)

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    event: "mouseover",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    alwaysOpen: false,
    icons: {
        "header": "yourIconClassClosed",
        "headerSelected": "yourIconClassOpen"
    }
});
```

And then set styles on those classes.